# Spring xd performance with message size

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I am finding below observations in spring xd

I have a stream like below

```
s3-source| processor-parser|http-client1|Request-construct-processor>queue

queue > processor|http-client2|processor|http-client3>queue
```

When my http-client output  json data of 2 kb i am able to process more message like  20k   msg per min. If data size is 26kb its so slow that it process 2000 msg per  min.Request-construct-processor   create  json using response from http and output string json.We have increased channel cache size to 1000.Currently my rabbit cpu utilization goes to 100% and it moves to flow state? Also as msg size increases I see slower msg rate and rabbit cpu increase?is there any way to over come this.

My  rabbit cpu is high and  it moves to flow state.
Msg rate has slowed down with increase in message size.
I am processing over million messages 3 container one admin and 3 rabbit all with 8 cpu and 32 gb ram machines.
I am running all module with concurrency with 10
I am also  passing http1  response also in message header  from Request-construct-processor
Also  i  see  lot of msg  in  transport queues in   between processors  and they are in idle stage and xd stops processing.

Update 2

I  was passing 26 kb in header and I removed it now i see good performance.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can make use of `batchSize` and `batchTimeout` properties for Rabbit message bus that could improve the performance.

For more detail you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#application-configuration)